# Prevent users submitting a form using Enter but enable enter key on one form input field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit

So I have a form with jQuery that prevents the user submitting the form using the enter key.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code prevents user submitting form using the enter button - must use submit button.
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    .....
});
```

How do I now permit the enter key to be used in one input field if I have the id? The enter key should only work on that one form input field.

Can this also be done using the input field css instead of the id?

Can this also be done using the input field name?

Here is the input field:

```
<input id="id_tags__tagautosuggest" name="tags" type="text" class="kmw-disabled keymanweb-font">
```

I have tried several attempts and googled an answer, but I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.target.id` to prevent and allow particular inputs.

```
 $(window).keydown(function(event){      
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          if(event.target.id==="allowedInput"){
            alert('submit form')
          }else{
            alert('not submitting')
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }

        }
    });
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(window).keydown(function(event) {

  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    if (event.target.id === "allowedInput") {
      alert('submit form')
    } else {
      alert('not submitting')
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="allowedInput" name="allowedInput" type="text" class="kmw-disabled keymanweb-font">

<input id="notallowedInput" name="notallowedInput" type="text" class="kmw-disabled keymanweb-font">
```

As certainperformance suggested you can use selector to match the input too

for ex `event.target.matches("#allowedInput")` this will match the input with selector, you can add your name or class name too.

Comment: To be more flexible, check if `event.target.matches` a particular selector.

Answer (score 2):

i share the simpler solution...

you can add class `.disable_enter` to input that you want to disable `submit-by-enter`..

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="field1" class="disable_enter" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" class="disable_enter" />
    <input type="text" name="field3" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
$('form .disable_enter').on('keydown keypress keyup', function(e){
  if( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Only `field3` will be allowed to be `submit-by-enter`..

Check out this fiddle for your ease: http://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/vu1b7gfs/

|------------------------|

|------------------------|

Or, you can do reverse.. disable enter for all input... but use class `.enable-enter` instead to enable `submit-by-enter`..

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="text" name="field3" class="enable_enter" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
$('form *').not('.enable_enter').on('keydown keypress keyup', function(e){
  if( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Only `field3` will be allowed to be `submit-by-enter`..

Check out this fiddle for your ease: http://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/h567mtnq/

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about "not jquery" --> http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
 $('window').not('#id_tags__tagautosuggest').keydown(function(event){

   //Your code...
   if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

});
```